# Are the terms 'shell prompt' and 'command prompt' interchangeable?

Tags: command-line

These terms get thrown around a lot and they seem to be the same, but is there a subtle difference?

Trying to prepare for a degree in programming so I want to make sure I don't screw up with any of the terms in an interview!

Comment: You can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21016640/2807183 this is for Windows but I think for your purpose it should be very much the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command prompt usually refers to the one Windows is using (`cmd.exe`) while a shell usually refers to the one Linux is using (usually `bash` or `sh`). The command prompt (`cmd.exe`) is also a shell, but the term "shell" gets used a lot more in Linux. And both of these are text-based (CLI) shells. `explorer.exe` is also a shell, although it's a graphical shell. Confusing, isn't it?

Basically, the Linux shell is more advanced than the command prompt. It gives users way more flexibility in commands and scripts than the command prompt.

Examples include but not limited to: way more complex commands (completely achieveable with `cmd`), way more complex string manipulation, more diverse built-in tools

Remember: we also have Powershell in Windows which IMO is Microsoft's attempt to be as good as `bash`. Yes, we have a lot of shells.

Answer (score 0):

yes but no.

Command Prompt refers to the Windows' CMR as a whole, thus the program that you start by either typing CMR.exe into the start > search box or clicking on the icon.

In Linux when we refer to this window that has a text interface in it we call it "a terminal" or with any of the generic names "an xterm, konsole, gnome-terminal".

THE shell is a program, which is also the program that you can use from one of these terminals, it is also a generic term for a type of programs and these can be several: bash, zsh, csh, dash, the busybox shell...

And the SHELL PROMPT refers quite specifically to tow things: The point were you insert text in the terminal window and the text that is displayed there, such as the "$", the "#" and similar.

Actually when we write "insert something at the shell prompt" we literally mean *write something into the shell as soon as you see the (empty) prompt appearing*

Comment: Did you mean: `cmd.exe` and not "cmr"?

Comment: Wow, you are right! 
CMR is an internal term of my company ("Custom Made Report").
LOL